# How to close file descriptor via Linux shell command

Tags: linux, shell, file-descriptor

In `/proc/pid/fd/`, there are too many file descriptors. Can I use shell command to close these file descriptors?

Comment: Which process is it? Is it your program? Can you post some source?

Comment: I had a case where some commercial app opened the same file with more than 1000 file descriptors, then ran out of file descriptors. The application was even unable to terminate though its own commands, so I had to kill it. If I were able to close some of the file descriptors, the program might have been able to terminate more cleanly.

Answer (score 41):

You can definitely close fd's of other running processes as long as you have the permissions to do so.

First, find the PID.

Then, start gdb and attach to the process:

```
gdb -p 1598
```

Then, call the close system call on the fd you want to close:

```
(gdb) call close(999)
$1 = 0
```

If the file descriptor was a leaked one, then the program will never try to use it again anyway, and it shouldn't cause any issues.  The program most likely has a bug, however.

Answer (score 12):

You can close a FD `n` of the current process in bash as so:

```
exec n<&-
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is used to close FD of the current process (bash process). Do you know any method to close FD of specific process?

Answer (score 4):

@Thomas answer is valid only when debug information for `close()` call is installed.

Without debug info installed, gdb refuses to call `close()`:

```
(gdb) call close(3)
'close' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type
```

The simplest way to make gdb call `close()` in this case is to cast the call to `close()` return type:

```
(gdb) call (int)close(3)
$1 = 0
```

See gdb [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Calling.html):

> Sometimes, a function you wish to call is missing debug information.
>   In such case, GDB does not know the type of the function, including
>   the types of the function’s parameters. To avoid calling the inferior
>   function incorrectly, which could result in the called function
>   functioning erroneously and even crash, GDB refuses to call the
>   function unless you tell it the type of the function.
>
> For prototyped (i.e. ANSI/ISO style) functions, there are two ways to
>   do that. The simplest is to cast the call to the function’s declared
>   return type.

Comment: Probably due to aggressive modern symbol table stripping: close() being a system call, it should be known to any process that uses the shared C library.

Answer (score 3):

I've ran in a similar situation, but where `gdb`was not an option since it disrupted the real-time constraints of my application and distorted my test.

So I came up with a quick `iptables` rule. *Optional arguments put into square brackets (`[ opt ]`)*.

1. **Find your destination address and port**:

   `netstat --program [ --numeric-host --numeric-ports ] | grep [<pid>]/[<appname>]`

   ```
   $ netstat --program --numeric-ports | grep 8812/
   tcp        0      0 ysc.xxx:54055          10.56.1.152:30000           ESTABLISHED 8812/my-application
   tcp        0      0 ysc.xxx:46786          postgres.xxx:5432           ESTABLISHED 8812/my-application
   tcp        0      0 ysc.xxx:36090          10.56.4.79:57000            ESTABLISHED 8812/my-application
                                         ...
   unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7177020 8812/my-application
   ```

   Here, I'd like to cut `10.56.4.79:57000`.
2. **Create an `iptables` rule to cut the socket**:

   `iptables -A OUTPUT [ --out-interface <if> --protocol <tcp|udp|unix> ] --destination <addr> --dport <port> --jump DROP`

   ```
   $ iptables -A OUTPUT --destination 10.56.4.79 --dport 57000 --jump DROP
   $
   ```
3. **At this stage**, your program can't send packets to the distant host. In most cases, **the TCP connection is closed**. You can proceed with your tests if there is some.

   ```
   $ netstat --program --numeric-ports | grep 8812/
   tcp        0      0 ysc.xxx:54055          10.56.1.152:30000           ESTABLISHED 8812/my-application
   tcp        0      0 ysc.xxx:46786          postgres.xxx:5432           ESTABLISHED 8812/my-application
                                         ...
   unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7177020 8812/my-application
   ```
4. **Remove the `iptables` rule**:

   You just type in the same `iptables` rule replacing the `A` by a `D`.

   ```
   $ iptables -D OUTPUT --destination 10.56.4.79 --dport 57000 --jump DROP
   $
   ```

Comment: Note that my intention was to test how my application would react if it lost its connection to a critical service.

Comment: The question was generic to file descriptors; your answer is for network connections only. And most of all, it does *not* close the file descriptor; it just drops the network traffic.

Comment: @U.Windl If your application behaves correctly, this leads to the end of that TCP connection and of the file descriptor. As I said in my answer "In most cases, the TCP connection is closed." It is not a panacea, but if it can help people...

Comment: Only if "keepalive" option is being used in TCP: Otherwise dead connections can stay there until closed or being reset.

Comment: This may not have been an answer to the question asked exactly, but it helped me do what I was trying to do.

Answer (score -6):

You can't just go around closing other processes' file descriptors and expect them to keep working.

Fix the program which has too many files open to make it open fewer. This may be a config change, or modifying the source etc. You can't just close the files for it.

Comment: Sure you can.  A common case for wanting to do this is because the program leaks fd's; in which case it will never use those again.  Sure, it's a bug, but it's still valid to want to work around it.

Comment: In my case, I had a long-running hung batch process because a read from an http socket had died. Closing the fd as @ThomasVanderStichele described solved the problem for me :-)

Comment: And what if you don't have access to the programs source code?

Comment: You can't tell a Unix hacker they can't do something. That is not how it works.